# Python Code Button Check

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am not an experienced python programmer. Honest, more like not at all. In my code, I set up two two push buttons to the PIN 3 and 2. I want the functions (not shown), Shutdown or ExitEmulator, to run when I press the appropriate button. Please see my partial code below

```
POWER_BTN_PIN = 3  #power button GPIO Pin 
RESET_BTN_PIN = 2 #reset button GPIO Pin 

GPIO.setup(POWER_BTN_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)    #INPUT:  Setup POWER button
GPIO.setup(RESET_BTN_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)    #INPUT:  Setup RESET button

GPIO.add_event_detect(POWER_BTN_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=Shutdown, bouncetime = 2000) 
GPIO.add_event_detect(RESET_BTN_PIN, GPIO.RISING, callback=ExitEmulator,bouncetime = 2000)
```

When I compile the script on my raspberry pi, I get a warning (see below):

[image: console_raspberry_pi]

```
'RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!'
```

Questions:
1. Is my setup correct?
2. Do the warnings matter? Will this potentially harm my raspberry pi?

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: [How to sort out "RuntimeWarning: A physical pull up resistor is fitted on this channel!"?](//raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/66447)

Answer (score 0):

That looks safe to me. Are the buttons powered or membrane? Powered buttons could mess with power distribution. Just be careful you don't blow a resister. If it's membrane it should be fine. Good Luck!